# JWT created on server but not being sent/set in browser

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, jwt, response

I am trying to set a JWT cookie for the response of a successful login in my Express app.

In the following code the user has been returned correctly from the DB and the `jwt.sign()` function is working correctly, ie. the token prints in the `console.log`

```
  app.get('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    ... // perform database lookup here 

    // Set up JWT for the returned user
    const secret = 'secretKey';
    const options = { expiresIn: '1h' };
  
    const token = jwt.sign(user, secret, options);
    console.log('the token -> ', token);

    res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });

    console.log('res.headers (check for cookie) -> ', res);
    // this logs the entire response object at the end of 
    // which Set-Cookie is present and contains the previously 
    // created JWT.   

    res.send(user)
 }
```

The JWT is clearly being set in the response headers under `Set-Cookie`.

The problem is the cookie is not appearing in the dev tools of the client. As a result it is not being sent in the headers of subsequent requests.

It's the first time I have tried to implement JWT so I could be missing something basic. If anyone has any suggestions how to remedy this I'd much appreciate the help.

**EDIT**

I have tested the JWT that is being produced in the server route using the tool at jwt.io and it comes back as an invalid signature even though it shows the correct user data in the decoded window. I'm not sure if this itself is causing the token not to be sent to/stored on the client but there is obviously something going wrong while encoding the JWT.

Comment: Does the cookie appear in the `Set-Cookie` header of the response, on the dev tools network tab? (Not sure what you meant with "in the dev tools".)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen By 'dev tools' I mean in `application>storage>cookies`. I have checked Network tab and don't see anything labeled `Set-Cookie`. Thanks!

Comment: Look at network tab > Headers > Response headers > Set-Cookie. If that is missing, your `res.cookie` statement does not work as expected. Can you share your entire middleware function?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen There is no `Set-Cookie` in the response headers. But when I log the response in the Express route before being sent the 'Set-Cookie' is present and populated with the JWT cookie (I will update my question to reflect this), so I have no idea why it is not getting to the browser. Regarding middleware, I don't have any set up for this function. Right now, the JWT code in my question is hard-coded into the route itself.

Comment: By "middleware", I meant the `function(req, res) {...}` that handles a route. Seems that the response lacking the cookie is _not_ produced by the code you shared.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have added the outer code for route to my question but I don't think it really adds anything useful. It's just a basic route in which a DB call is made to find a user. When the user comes back the JWT is created in the callback and the the `res.send` completes it. I will say that when this call is finished that a new call for data on a different route happens automatically. So, you are probably right that the response I am seeing in the browser is the second one. That said, shouldn't the JWT cookie still be stored somewhere in the browser? Thanks again!

Comment: Are you using some browser extensions or settings (privacy filters, adblockers, etc) that manipulate the response by stripping cookies?

Comment: httpOnly will do that, client-side scripts cant access HTTP only cookies :(, *As a result it is not being sent in the headers of subsequent requests.* it will if you don't attempt to overwrite them

Comment: @Bergi There are no privacy filters etc. that I am aware of in place.

Comment: @mikeym Still, try a different browser. Also is there any network middleware or middlebox in between your browser and your node server? Where are you running them?

Comment: @Bergi I have tried in a different browser and still don't get the cookie sent to the client. As for middleware, there is nothing else in the route that is between the initial request and the response. I am running everything on localhost on my personal machine. My front end and back end are on different ports though, so maybe there is a cross-domain issue going on but I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe both browser block third-party (cross-origin) cookies by default? The header still should show up in the response in the devtools network panel though (even if not in the application cookies). Try using the same origin, and also try the request with a non-browser tool such as postman or curl.